# Android library overlay rectangle disappears

Tags: android, camera, overlay

I have a library that shows a camera preview. I want to add a rectangle overlay on top of the preview. I tried 2 different approaches. But both of them display the rectangle shortly then disappear.

1. approach (using view.getOverlay)

   ```
   mPreview.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
   mPreview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
   ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
   rootView.addView(mPreview);

   final ViewOverlay overlay = mPreview.getOverlay();
   final Bracket bracket = new Bracket();
   mPreview.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           bracket.setBounds(0, 0, mPreview.getWidth(), mPreview.getHeight());
           overlay.add(bracket);
       }
   });
   ```
2. approach (overriding draw function in surfaceview)

   ```
   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.draw(canvas);

       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

       //center
       int x0 = canvas.getWidth()/2;
       int y0 = canvas.getHeight()/2;
       int dx = canvas.getHeight()/3;
       int dy = canvas.getHeight()/3;
       //draw guide box
       canvas.drawRect(x0-dx, y0-dy, x0+dx, y0+dy, paint);
   }
   ```

mPreview extends SurfaceView

Bracket extends Drawable

**UPDATE**

If I use `setContentView` instead of `rootView.addView` it works as expected. But in this case I can not remove the view.

Comment: You can add an imageView above the SurfaceView - even in your xml!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a new `Activity` and `setContentView`. That solved the problem.
To remove the view I `finish`ed the action.